# how to show ordinal axis in d3

Tags: d3.js, scale, axis

I am new to d3 and having issue with showing the label of ordinal axis:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3: Loading data from a CSV file</title>
  </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
      w = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      h = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      var padding = 40;
      
      var data = [
        { "Food": "Apples", "Deliciousness": 9 },
        { "Food": "Green Beans", "Deliciousness": 5 },
        { "Food": "Egg Salad Sandwich", "Deliciousness": 4 },
        { "Food": "Cookies", "Deliciousness": 10 },
        { "Food": "Liver", "Deliciousness": 2 },
        { "Food": "Burrito", "Deliciousness": 7 },
      ];

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Deliciousness = +d.Deliciousness;
      });

      var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left+"," +
                 margin.top+")");
        
      var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
       .domain(d=>d.Food)
       .range([0,w])
       .paddingInner(0.2);
     xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Food; }));
        
      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
       .scale(xScale)
       .ticks(5);
      
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
       .domain([0, d3.max(data, d=>d.Deliciousness)])
       .rangeRound([h,0]);
        
      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
       .scale(yScale)
       .ticks(5);
      
      svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i*w/data.length)
        .attr('y',d=>yScale(d.Deliciousness))
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('height',d =>h-yScale(d.Deliciousness))
        .attr('fill',function(d){
          if (d===30) return "red";
          return "rgb(0,0,"+d.Deliciousness*10+")" ;});
       
      svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .text(d=>d.Deliciousness)
       .attr("x", (d,i)=>(padding + i*w/data.length))
        .attr("y", d=>yScale(d.Deliciousness)+15)
       .attr("fill","white");
      
      svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
       .call(yAxis);
        
   svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h-margin.bottom) + ")")
       .call(xAxis);
        
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The x axis is somehow overlapping with the chart, how to properly use the margin?

And in terms of ordinal axis, other than list all the categories manually in .domain(), what are the other ways to special xScale in .domain().range() call? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the location definition of the x-axis.

You can change:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h-margin.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

with:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + h + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

---

Here is the demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3: Loading data from a CSV file</title>
  </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
      w = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      h = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      var padding = 40;
      
      var data = [
        { "Food": "Apples", "Deliciousness": 9 },
        { "Food": "Green Beans", "Deliciousness": 5 },
        { "Food": "Egg Salad Sandwich", "Deliciousness": 4 },
        { "Food": "Cookies", "Deliciousness": 10 },
        { "Food": "Liver", "Deliciousness": 2 },
        { "Food": "Burrito", "Deliciousness": 7 },
      ];

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Deliciousness = +d.Deliciousness;
      });

      var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right + padding)
      .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left+"," +
                 margin.top+")");
        
      var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
       .domain(d=>d.Food)
       .range([0,w])
       .paddingInner(0.2);
     xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Food; }));
        
      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
       .scale(xScale)
       .ticks(5);
      
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
       .domain([0, d3.max(data, d=>d.Deliciousness)])
       .rangeRound([h,0]);
        
      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
       .scale(yScale)
       .ticks(5);
      
      svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i * ((w + 20 ) / data.length))
        .attr('y',d=>yScale(d.Deliciousness))
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('height',d =>h-yScale(d.Deliciousness))
        .attr('fill',function(d){
          if (d===30) return "red";
          return "rgb(0,0,"+d.Deliciousness*10+")" ;});
       
      svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .text(d=>d.Deliciousness)
       .attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i * ((w + 20 ) / data.length))
        .attr("y", d=>yScale(d.Deliciousness)+15)
       .attr("fill","white");
      
      svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
       .call(yAxis);
        
   svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + h + ")")
       .call(xAxis);
        
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

`x-axis` location compared to its container (here `svg`) is defined by the `transform` attribute. Which in this case is a translation. To define a translation, we give to the transform attribute this value: `translate(dx,dy)`.

**dx**: As `rect`s are given a x offset of `margin.left` (`.attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i*w/data.length)`) we also need to translate the x-axis horizontally by `margin.left`.

**dy**: And as `rect`s have their base starting at `h` (`.rangeRound([h, 0]);`), we also need to translate the x-axis vertically by `h`.

---

I have also modified the x position of bars and labels using:

```
.attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i * ((w + margin.right ) / data.length))
```

instead of:

```
.attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i*w/data.length)
```

---

Finally, as the last bar is half outside the graph, you can increase the svg container's width, by replacing:

```
.attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
```

with:

```
.attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right + padding)
```

---

Concerning your final question, this https://github.com/d3/d3-axis might give you additional details on how to use d3 axes.

Comment: thanks so much for ur reply, Xavier. I can show axis label now, but chart still a bit strange: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/a86e5ffe4faf764b08ca0cb7b9246907
for one thing, the label isn't in the middle of the bar, also the bar didn't start from 0.

Comment: You've modified `.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")` in between. It was `.attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")` when you asked the question.

Comment: i got rid of padding since I was using paddingInner(0.2) instead.

Comment: Could you try with you initial code and the two line changes and check it's good for you?

Comment: works great, but i think the paddingInner is still causing some shifting, such as in  'Burrito'

Comment: Just updated the answer. You can increase the width of the `svg` container to correctly display the half displayed right bar.